# Can't play some Vimeo videos. Is it possible to set Referer request header on ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, video, ionic3, vimeo

I have both an Web application and a Mobile (Ionic) application that has this feature to play Vimeo videos uploaded by the user to the Vimeo account configured in the environment.

So in the web application, I'm able to play the video in the component mounting a simple player.vimeo url this way:

```
    function getUrlVimeo(videoid) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("//player.vimeo.com/video/" + videoid);
    }
```

And so the api request looks like that:

[Vimeo API request to play video (web-side) (internal redirect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGh9M.png)

[Vimeo API request to play video (web-side)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvij1.png)

Note the Referer request header: the url that's sent on this header is the web application url.

But I've noticed I can't play the same video on Mobile (Ionic) application probably because of the **Referer** request header, that is sent correctly when on web application because the browser does it automatically, but the same doesn't happen on Ionic 3 Mobile application.

Code sample inside `ngOnInit()` method on the page that reproduces the video on Mobile application, `this.href` is set as the video id for the Vimeo Video component:

```
console.log('video-link-player-vimeo page .... ngOnInit()');

if(this.isCourse) {
  this.href = this.conteudoVideoDetail.data.href;
} else {
  this.href = this.trailContent.data.href;
}

var options01 = {
    id: this.href
};

this.Vimeo = window['Vimeo'];
this.player = new window['Vimeo'].Player('player_vimeo', options01);
```

But this causes the following privacy error:

[Privacy error on ionic mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgemI.png)

The API request on Mobile looks like that:

[Vimeo API request to play video (mobile - ionic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq9V2.png)

I believe if I could set the **Referer** request header to the the environment url (same as web), it would work, but Ionic automatically sets it to `http://localhost/` and I can't seem to find a way to change it.

Is there any way I can do that or overcome this privacy setting error in any way?